# Pass select statment as an argument to sql function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have function:

```
create or replace function provide_city_name(id_offer int)
returns varchar                                       
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
   city_record record;                               
begin
   select id, type, parent_id, name 
   into city_record                             
   from location
   where id = id_offer;
   
   if city_record.type < 6 then                
    return city_record.name;                    
   else
    return provide_city_name(city_record.parent_id); 
   end if;
end;
$$;
```

What I want to do is to pass a SELECT result as an argument of a function.
My select statment: `select offer_id from offers limit 5`
My result is:

```
     offer_id
1    146
2    147
3    148
4    149
5    150
```

I would like to convert this by my function:

```
select provide_city_name(select offer_id from offers limit 5)
```

And result should looks like

```
     offer_id
1    New York
2    Las Vegas
3    London
4    New York
5    Moscow
```

How can I run my function with argument select statment?

Comment: `select provide_city_name(offer_id) AS city_name from offers limit 5` ?

Comment: @clamp It generated an error:
```
ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded Hint: Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
```

Comment: This was about how to call it for the 5 offer_ids. If you need help on the function, you should edit your post and include the table definitions.

Comment: @clamp So I can not run this function for a few offer_ids, can I? If I understand correct I need to change my function, am I right?

Comment: Please edit your question, add table definition and sample data. Your functions code does not handle data with circular dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres **9.3** or later, you could try to use a **LATERAL join**:

```
SELECT o.id, o.name 
FROM   offers O
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL provide_city_name(o.offer_id) f ON true
```